# .lst file generation in cmake

Tags: cmake

I want to generate `.lst` files for my source file. I am successfully able to generate the executable.
But I don't know how to generate `.lst` files for my source files.

```
get_property(allsrcfiles TARGET myExe PROPERTY SOURCES)
foreach(srcfile IN LISTS allsrcfiles)
set_source_files_properties(${srcfile} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wa, anhlmsd=${srcfile}.lst")
endforeach()
```

I have added the above script in my `CMakelists.txt`, if I add the above script I am getting the following error

```
[100%] Linking C executable myExe
dld: error: Can't open file 'CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/src/sample.c.obj': No such file or directory
CMakeFiles\myExe.dir\build.make:101: recipe for target 'myExe' failed gmake[2]: *** [myExe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:93: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/all' failed
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:101: recipe for target 'all' failed
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

`sample.c.obj` file is getting generated without `source_file_properties`.

```
compiler : WIND RIVER
Target : ppc - embedded
Host : windows
```

is list file generation commands depends on the compiler?

Comment: I know nothing about wind river, but I was curious, so did some googling for `anhlmsd`. All the examples I found had `-Wa, -anhlmsd` while your example is lacking the `-` in front of `anhlmsd`. Not sure if that's an issue or not.

Comment: it is a typo error.. with "-" also no improvement in the output

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-Wa,-anhlmsd`, without the space in bewteen? Please compile in verbose mode (`cmake ... --verbose` or `make VERBOSE=1`) and show the compile commands. So does the file `CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/src/sample.c.obj` exist?